# Jenkins pipeline powershell wrong format in console output

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I get strange output with powershell pipeline in Jenkins 2.77 (Windows machine)

```
node('build') {
    stage('From sharedlibrary') {
        powershell 'Write-Output "Hello, World!"'
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[QA_SharedLibrary] Running PowerShell script ï»¿Hello, World!
```

I tried add -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 to each build machine, but no result.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found problem it's bug inside plugin https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46496